# How to create a C# null object in matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have an C#/.NET library that I'm calling from Matlab.  Matlab/C# integration overall is [amazing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html?searchHighlight=.NET&s_tid=srchtitle).  However, for this library, I want to pass NULL into several methods, and I can't figure out how to finagle Matlab to do so.

One might think [libpointer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libpointer.html) would work, but libpointer is for C library calls, not C#/.NET.

What I have implemented to date, is a method in C# in a separate library that does the following:

```
  public static Object getNullObject()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

But, I would like to do this in pure matlab, and there is no way that I can see to do it in pure matlab.

Comment: Which C# library do you use? How do you integrate it with Matlab?

Comment: I checked here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/rules-for-data-conversion-between-net-and-matlab.html There is no `null` conversion rule in any of the conversion tables...

Comment: Can you pass `null` *from the C# side to the Matlab side*, and check the Matlab value you get? If this is not possible, then at least you will get an error that confirms this.

Comment: @kol, yes, that is my backup plan, but I was hoping to not have to write C# code to accomplish this.

Comment: If you figure out the answer, please post it here.

Comment: Can you just pass []? That seems to be the answer according to this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-net-data-in-matlab.html#bte9o8y-1